# I can't ask questions even if there are only 2 questions with negative points, why?

Tags: support, questions, reputation, post-ban

I have been actively asking and answering but now it seems like just because of some negative votes I am unable to ask questions, and downvotes don't even leave the comments.

Comment: Something's not right.  You don't have any recent questions or answers.

Comment: Have you deleted questions? That does not help.

Comment: No i didn't delete any questions, it won't let me as people has answered it.

Answer (score 6):

If we compute [your](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/324939/pradyuman?tab=questions&sort=newest) [question record](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290545/280545), we find:

- 10 total questions
- 2 deleted questions
- 4 negative-scored questions
- 4 closed questions

$$
\frac{
\text{total} - \text{negative} - \text{closed} - \text{deleted}
}{
\text{total}
}
= 0
$$

A "good" question record is a score above 0.5, so you appear to be underestimating the impact of your old questions.

The exact details of the question ban are secret, but there is some general guidance.  You are probably up against [the soft rate-limiting question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/280545) rather than [the hard question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/280545), which means that you'll be able to ask questions again at some unspecified time in the near future, and that your question-asking privileges may be influenced by other positive interactions with the site.

Comment: An interesting psychological phenomena seems to arise with many of these questions - many folks deny deleting questions, yet it turns out that they have...

Comment: Or the posts were deleted by the Community bot, or the users have forgotten about their deleted post. On another site where I'm a low-rep user, my deleted question doesn't show in my question history. There is a "deleted questions" link at the bottom of my activity, but I just overlooked it twice (and found the question in a more roundabout way), even though I was visiting that profile specifically to see how deleted questions appear.

Comment: @JonCuster well the deleted questions were before ban, when I thought they were not relevant.

Comment: @Pradyuman If we look only at your questions in 2023, I count a question record if 0.25, which is still not "good." I suggest you wait a week or so — during which time you might contribute constructive edits, high-quality answers, and spend some time curating our review queues.

Comment: @Jon Custer: Yes, this is observed very frequently at Stack Overflow. Though some of it may be due to *automatic* deletion by the system (e.g., of low-scored questions without any answers(?) after some time (30 days?)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen - indeed. Perhaps the tour should mention that deleted questions are not good. Auto delete criteria are there for a reason though, but double counting auto deleted questions does seem a bit punitive. There is overhead in tracking them separately so I doubt that would happen.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The help center describes when [the Community bot deletes questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions).